# How can I turn on flashlight in old devices

Tags: android

I'm trying to run flashlight on old devices especially lower than API level 21 but unfortunately I got error

*Error*

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.flashlight.app/com.test.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

*Code*

```
android.hardware.Camera camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
     android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
     android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

From Android 6 (API level 23) on the permissions are asked in runtime but for old versions they had to be in the Manifest.

And also ask for that permissions at runtime as you did for new devices, you have to ask for the permissions in both ways.

Comment: OK , It's working but not working on the new devices

Comment: But also ask them at runtime, as I think you did, for new devices. You have to ask for them in both ways